# Format of settlement statement - NSNP

Tags: canada, immigration

I am applying for Canada immigration under NOVA SCOTIA demand - express entry program.

To seek a nomination from this province, I need to write the statement of intent in my application form.

Do we have certain formats to follow for writing such settlement statements?

What are the core points that has to be addressed, when a principal applicant(with family) is applying for nomination?

The actual statement in the application is in the "Settlement" section and says:

> *In your own words*, tell us briefly about your plans to settle in Nova
>   Scotia and your future here. Statements copied from someone or
>   somewhere else are not acceptable.

Note: The phrase "In your own words" is underlined, not italicized in the original document.

Answer (score 3):

There is no given format because the authorities want this to be a personal statement. Some of the information you *might* include could be where in Nova Scotia you want to settle, would you come first to get a job and family arrive later, what does your wife and daughter think about moving, and how would you all try to settle in and build a new life?

In particular, they probably want to hear why Nova Scotia? Why not Toronto or Vancouver? If you or your wife grew up in a small town or a rural area and want to live somewhere similar, that might be a plus (don't lie or stretch the truth, of course).

It's similar to a cover letter for a job or university application.

Comment: I learnt that Nova scotia province is very strict in their screening of applications. I gave 3 points in settlement. Why halifax as per my career background? What would my daughter like to do? what would my wife like to pursue in her career?